# How do I see my inputs?

Tags: controllers, emulation

I use my emulators to take some of my console games on the go.

I want to write some scripts to use with my controllers/emulators.

I am running Windows 7x64. I use several usb devices (game controllers and drawing tablet being the two main ones I'm concerned with).

I have controllers which use xinput, dinput and the tablet has some hid buttons... one of the controllers has a gyro (and maybe a compass as well?), and (the gyro at least) works properly (I can, for example, drive a car in game using motion controls). These settings are kinda scattered around my driver program and individual games...

I need a utility that can display what input is active (what button I'm pressing, or axis is active), without having to go looking for it. This makes mapping the buttons/axis properly to their counter parts rights... sometimes, I just get confused (the mixture of xinputs, dinputs and hid inputs)

i.e.: when I have my motion sensor controller plugged in, I want to see what each button pressed is (LButton, Button1 or ButtonOne or whatever the command name of the button is, etc) including the axis (the 2 sticks and gyro), so I can use them in scripts more easily (I just always forget which is which, and which names for dinput and xinput since I do things like things infrequently). Sort of like the "display keystrokes" utilities, but that includes controller inputs as well. If it includes the exact stick movement that'd be great.

I really only need this for the dinput/xinput (I assume the gyro function is covered n there?), but it would be great if such a thing also exists that can show me what the hid input commands are (though I understand this might be another matter altogether, a link to info on this would be appreciated as well).

To be clear: I am not looking for raw data, unless I can get that from the same utility (without added hardware) or anything low level, I just want to see what the inputs are recognized as by Windows. I would also take a reference sheet of xinput/dinput commands that show what buttons/axis names are for use in mapping and scripting.

Sorry if this should be obvious or easy to find, it seems to bring up a lot of more technical work (involving arduinos and other stuff) when I try to research it. Maybe I am just being dense or obtuse.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a tool recommendation.  I'm not sure that this is directly applicable to the gaming site.  Perhaps a developer site would have more info for you.

Comment: I did try that, but I thought it might fit here because a) I am trying to find this tool or function for use with my emulator, and b) it is a useful function/tool... a bit like macros tools for certain games or some other such things I've seen.  But I also see your point, I leave it up to you.

Comment: I made a Meta thread about this question to see if we can tweak it and get it reopened. Feel free to join in on the discussion: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8347/can-we-rephrase-this-question-to-make-it-fit

Answer (score 5):

Windows has a controllers page that does exactly this. Getting to it differs depending on the version of Windows you're running.

- [Windows XP](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/cpl_joy_test.mspx?mfr=true)
- Windows 7: Click on Hardware and Sound and then Devices and Printers. Alternatively, click on Devices and Printers in the Start Menu - by default, this is listed below Control Panel. (Taken from [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/gaming/13968-game-controllers.html#post139430)).

If you don't see your controller in this page, you need to install the Windows drivers for it to work properly.

Comment: So this method, which I am aware of, doesn't really help.  Yes, it identifies the buttons, but not how the buttons are referred to programatically... it's the same display regardless of xinput or dinput controller being attached, yes, the one lights up when I press the corresponding button, but what is that button called (Button1 vs Button One vs BttnOne vs all the different ways you can say it that could work but don't, since only some names are recognized as being that input).  As for using in controller scripts to load into the emulators or other scripting tools to add functions to my games

Comment: If you're looking for scripting, that is off-topic for Arqade, I'm afraid.  We can help you get it running, but we're not here in any sort of coding capacity, unless it's code in-game.